# ejb transaction ignore exception

Tags: java, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

hy all,

i have a beans:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
Class A {

public void methodeA(){
try{
 ejbRemote1.xxx()
}
catch(Exception ex) {
log.error(ex)
}
...
methodeB();
...
}

public void methodeB(){
try{
 ejbRemote2.yyy()
}
catch(Exception ex) {
log.error(ex)
}

}

}
```

the methode xxx() is defined in the ejb remote with notation @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

the methode yyy() is difined in the remote ejb with notation @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

my problem i call with success the methode xxx(), my case is the methode xxx() throw ZZZException extend runtimeException (is ok when this methode throw a ZZZException , is a functional need)
my eroor is loged in my file logger.
but the problem when the thread go to call the methode yyy() my thread not go in the method yyy() but throw immediatly a ZZZException the same exception throw when i call xxx() and i get this exeption in the server console

```
<27 juil. 2016 10 h 45 CEST> <Notice> <EJB> <BEA-010014> <Error occurred while attempting to rollback transaction: javax.transaction.SystemException: Timeout during rollback processing
javax.transaction.SystemException: Timeout during rollback processing
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.internalRollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:433)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.rollback(ServerTransactionImpl.java:387)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:862)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.handleSystemException(BaseRemoteObject.java:809)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseRemoteObject.postInvoke1(BaseRemoteObject.java:518)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

i need to ignor in case the methode xxx() throw exception just i log the error but i need to excecute the yyy() with no problem

the methode xxx() is in another project i cant change transaction type or code 
but yyy() is in my project i cant fixe it

persistence is jta transaction.

weblogic 10.3.5

eclipselink 2.4.2

ejb 3

javaEE 5

thaks you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of why you are demarcating the transactions as you are, but if there is a runtime exception in your remote EJB call, the transaction wrapping it needs to be marked for rollback.  You need to look at why your transaction rollback is timing out - it likely doesn't have much to do with your method YYY call, though you really don't show enough to guess.  You might want to change your application to throw checked exceptions rather than RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: i can do another methodeC ZZZ where is TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW for ignore exception throw by methode xxx() and the methodeA call methodeC and methodeB ? i just like ignore exception runtime in the call the methode xxx()